# SignalR groups not invoked

Tags: signalr

I am doing my first tests with SignalR. I am toying with chat messages, but that's only a first step to replace all the polling from client to server which I have today on my site.

I have a lot of scenarios where I want to notify certain users either by their login or by their ID. The idea is that I am adding each user to two groups as soon as he connects. I do this in OnConnected and that event is called.

When I send a chat message, I have two modes: either public or personal. If it is personal the sender is notified and the recipient should be notified. The sender gets a message but the group never does. It seems to be impossible to found out how many members a group has.

Any ideas what's going wrong here?

```
public class GlobalHub:Hub
{
    private Users user;

    private void AuthenticateUser()
    {
        var ydc = new MyDataContext();
        user = ydc.Users.First(u => u.Login == HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
    }

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        var ydc = new MyDataContext();
        user = ydc.Users.First(u => u.Login == HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);

        Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, user.Login);
        Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, user.ID.ToString());
        return base.OnConnected();
    }


public void SendChatMessage(string message, string recipient)
{
    AuthenticateUser();
    var cm = ChatController.AddChatMessage(user.Login, user.ID, recipient, tmessage);

    if (recipient != "")
    {
        Clients.Caller.NewMessage(cm);
        Clients.Group(recipient).NewMessage(cm);
    }
    else
    {
        Clients.All.NewMessage(cm);
    } 
}
}
```

Comment: Your Hub code looks good.  I'd verify that SendChatMessage is getting called with the correct recipient.  Also is recipient supposed to be user.Login or user.ID.ToString() ?

Comment: recipient is the login. But it should work either way since I have each user in two groups :) But if the code looks great why is NewMessage called for All and for the Caller but not for the Group? Is there any way I can debug who's in which group???

Comment: Groups are a separate from the .All and the .Caller pieces.  You'll need to ensure that it's attempting to add your users to the appropriate groups.  As for being able to debug and to find out who's in what group: you wont be able to unless you include the SiganlR source and step through the source code.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that Groups.Add does not immediately join the connection to the group, but instead returns a Task, that needs to be started. Try returning the result of Groups.Add as result of OnConnectedMethod.

See also more detailed explanation at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15469038/174638