# SignalR: How does server correctly subscribe to a group when connection is established

Tags: asp.net, .net, signalr

I have look at the several places, but still can not find clear instructions on how groups should be used. I am using a groups for filtering (delivering the message just to subset of clients).

I would like to join a client to the group on the server side in `OnConnected` event. Client does not need to know to which groups it belongs.

Questions:

1. Should I also override the `OnReconnected` event?
2. Should I return the Task returned from `GroupManager.Add` as the result of `OnConnected` event? If I would like to join multiple groups, I probably need to create a combined task. Right?

3- Why does the server (see `GroupManager.Add` implementation) sends the `AddToGroup` command the client? Is there a way to work around this? Maybe by using `Client.AllExcept(...)` and manually handling group membership on the server (yuck!)?

I am using the latest version of SignalR (1.0.0.1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You do not need to override OnReconnected.  When a client reconnects it will rejoin all groups it was previously in.
2. You don't have to, but if you try sending to that group within the OnConnected (if you choose to not return the group addition task) you will need to wait until the task completes.
3. You do not want to work around this, one of the reasons its necessary is because of #2 (the client needs to know what groups it is in).  If you want to authenticate groups for reconnect you can always create a hub pipeline module and override the BuildRejoiningGroups function to perform your own verification.

**Response to Comments**

Comment 1: Yes
Comment 2: You must return a task otherwise nothing will complete (this is by design).  If you do not know what to return you can always return base.OnConnected().

When you call GroupManager.Add it returns a task that represents when the connection is in the desired group.  Once joining the group the client then gets notified that its now in a new group via a token.  The token will then allow the client to rejoin the group if it has to reconnect due to loss of connectivity.

Comment: So the reason for Ad3) - the client should know the groups he belongs to is that the client automatically sends the group membership on reconnection?

Comment: Ad2): If I do not return the Task from OnConnect, the client does not receive the message (even with 10 second delay on server side). See also  [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803682/signalr-groups-not-invoked). Who starts the task returned by `GroupManager.Add` if I do not return it from `OnConnected`? `MessageBus.ScheduleTopic` / `MessageBroker.Schedule`?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was returning new `Task(() => { })` from `OnConnected' method which was not OK. Since this task was not started. ` base.OnConnected()' returns Empty, already completed Task, which is OK. And if I understand correctly, `MessageBroker.Schedule` puts the join group message in a queue and `PumpImplAsync` actually starts the task of joining to a group.